# Can't add calendar event with '.ics' to Outlook 365

Tags: php, laravel

I can't seem to get my '.ics' file to work with Outlook 365 for Mac. When I try to right-click and open with Outlook, it just attaches it to a blank email. I've also tried just dragging and dropping it into my calendar but that doesn't seem to work.

It's working for Apple's iCal and all the information is transmitted properly there.

I'm generating the file in PHP like so:

```
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TestEvent.ics");
$file = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
$file .= "VERSION:2.0\n";
$file .= "PRODID:myappid\n";
$file .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\n";
$file .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
$file .= "UID:somerandomIDIgenerate\n";
$file .= "DTSTAMP:" . Carbon::now() . "\n";
$file .= "DTSTART:" . gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime($event->begin_time)) . "\n";
$file .= "DTEND:" . gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime($event->end_time)) . "\n";
$file .= "LOCATION:" . $event->location . "\n";
$file .= "SUMMARY:" . $event->summary . "\n";
$file .= "DESCRIPTION:" . $event->description . "\n";
$file .= "END:VEVENT\n";
$file .= "END:VCALENDAR\n";
echo $file;
```

Comment: it will try to attach itself to a blank email if the ical file is invalid. can you show the contents of an actual file you generated instead of the php code. also your DTSTAMP should be gmdate formatted

Comment: These are the contents of the actual file

Comment: Looks like changing the DTSTAMP to be gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z", strtotime(Carbon::now())) opened it as a new appointment that I had to save. Thanks for the help.